# Android: Can't display a radio button result in my AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm not having a problem with displaying a Toast with the result, but I am having trouble when I try and do the same thing in the .setMessage. Have tried concatenating ("You selected" + ......... ) but I'm now stuck.

```
private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(null);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("You selected")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want? Do you want to set the title to "You selected true" or "You selected false" or something else?

Comment: I want to say "You selected cat/dog/" etc. So whatever the choice made in the radio button list was - I want to display that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RadioButtonGroup`. From this group you can get the selected `RadioButton` and then the `value`.

Here is an example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/radiogroup/android-radiogroup-example/

You also could set an `onCheckedChangedListener` on your `RadioButtonGroup`. The code will look something like this:

`radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if(checkedId == R.id.cat) {
            //set selectedRadioButton variable
        } else if(checkedId == R.id.dog){
            //set variable
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you but the example shows things I've already done, I've uploaded a screen grab here in case this explains things better: http://lara.rufflecol.es/wp-content/uploads/2015-10-23.png

Comment: How do you try to set the text? Can you show some more code?

Comment: In my head I should be adding code here: .setMessage("You selected") - but I am guessing

Comment: Yes you need to add the value of the selected `RadioButton`. How are you trying to do that now?

Comment: I understand but I don't know how to do it and I can't find any examples via Google.